# ASP.NET Core SPA server rendering not working with react+redux+ant-design+babel-plugin-import

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, react-redux, server-rendering, antd

I generated a new ASP.NET Core SPA with React+Redux using the aspnetcore-spa generator from Microsoft and tried to use it with ant-design and [babel-plugin-import](https://github.com/ant-design/babel-plugin-import), and **the first time the page will be rendered successfully**, but once refreshing, it will throw the following error every time, even after restarting the dotnet application.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed
>   because of error: Error: Cannot find module "../../style/index.css" at
>   webpackMissingModule
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:595:66)
>   at Object.
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:595:164)
>   at **webpack_require**
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>   at Object.
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:387:13)
>   at **webpack_require**
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>   at Object.defineProperty.value
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:168:14)
>   at **webpack_require**
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>   at Object.
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:65:16)
>   at **webpack_require**
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:20:30)
>   at Object.defineProperty.value
>   (C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:40:18)
>   Current directory is:
>   C:\Users\viccrubs\Documents\Projects\QuestionSample1
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+d__7.MoveNext()

This babel plugin works well in a pure react+webpack+typescript project.
Manually importing a component from antd without the help of babel-plugin-import will also result in the same error.
It looks like an issue of wrong working directory, and the `../../style/index.css` does exist under the directory containing antd components, but it should have been processed by webpack.
And it's also strange that the first render works fine.

Sample:
https://github.com/viccrubs/QuestionSample1

or do the following to reproduce it:

1. Generate an ASP.NET Core with React+Redux project with that yeoman generator
2. npm install --save antd babel-plugin-import
3. Delete all the `ThunkAction` import from the files under /ClientApp/store
4. Add `"plugins":[["import", { "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]]` in .babelrc
5. Add any antd component in the Home.tsx
6. Add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,` in the tsconfig.json
7. dotnet run and open localhost:5000
8. It should be that the first render will cause no error, but once refreshing, the error above will show up.